# jquery, submit form when field loses focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I submit a form when a field (In this case the form only has one field) loses focus?

I tried this, but it's not working:

```
$("form").submit();
```

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention that the form was created with jquery as well:

```
$("div").html('<form action="javascript:void(0)" style="display:inline;"><input type="text" value="' + oldValue + '"></form>');
```

This is probably why it won't submit, I think it's because the events aren't being observed.

Comment: What do you hope to achieve with `action="javascript:void(0)"`?

Comment: meh, I don;t know something crappy the rails plugin i'm using decides to put in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trigger the form's [submit()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/submit) event when the field loses focus. You can detect this by attaching a [`blur()`](http://www.google.com.au/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enAU314AU317&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+blur) event handler to it.

```
$("#field").blur(function() {
  $("#form").submit();
});
```

If you field doesn't have an ID or other means of easily identifying it (which I would recommend) you could also do something like this:

```
$("#form :input").blur(function() {
  $("#form").submit();
});
```

since there's only one field.

Comment: How can you do this with a jQuery Validation Plugin? Thanks

Answer (score 10):

```
$('form :input').blur(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this

```
var $yourForm = $('#form');

$yourForm.find('input').eq(0).blur(function() {

    $yourForm.submit();
});
```