# How do i make my inline edit to send automatically without pressing enter?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, inline

I have a website where you can edit inline by clicking the table cell. After click and type the string, you need to press enter in order to update the data. My problem is, I want to automatically send the data without pressing enter. What key event should i use with this one?  onkeypress? and how would i remove the enter key event?

```
 $('td.edit').keydown(function(event){
            arr = $(this).attr('class').split( " " );
            if(event.which == 13)
            { 
                        $.ajax({type: "POST",
                        url: "../../controller/inline.php",
                        data: "value="+$('.ajax input').val()+"&rownum="+arr[2]+"&field="+arr[1]+"&ids="+'<?php echo isset($_POST['frmID'])?$_POST['frmID']:$_GET['id']; ?>'+"&dFrom="+'<?php echo isset($_POST['frmDateFrom']) ? $_POST['frmDateFrom']:date('n\/j\/Y', strtotime("-15 days")); ?>'+"&dTo="+'<?php echo isset($_POST['frmDateTo'])?$_POST['frmDateTo']:date('n\/j\/Y'); ?>',
                        success: function(data){
                            $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                            $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                                            }});


            }
});
```

Comment: How will you know when the user has stopped typing?

Comment: You're going to kill your server unless you throttle the update quite a bit.

Comment: i will know when the user clicks the web page

Comment: do you mean on the input losing focus?

Comment: yes, exactly what i mean - @dragon

Comment: well i was hoping spelling it out would lead you to the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857031/jquery-submit-form-when-field-loses-focus

Answer (score 0):

I believe an onBlur event is what you're looking for. 
http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: never link to w3schools

Comment: Fair enough. It just happened to be a top Google result and I got lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I experienced same situation too.

You really need to save automatically?

Simple solution is 'focusout()' or 'onBlur()' maybe.

But it is too risky.

It means just single miss click or miss key press firing save event.

If you have multiple columns to input somthing.

Don't do that.

But just single column, try 'onBlur()' or 'focusout()'

I'll waiting your wise solution. :3

Comment: i've tried onblur, i think its not a good idea, for now i'm experimenting on focusout

Answer (score 0):

What you can do (although I wouldn't recommend it) is to use a setTimeout to save the data. This way the user can keep on typing without saving, but once he stops typing for a second or so it will save the data.

Take a look at the example here (http://jsfiddle.net/G2LxD):

```
 var timer; 

 $('input').keyup(function() {
      if (timer !== null) {
         clearTimeout(timer);
         timer = null;
      }

      timer = setTimeout(function() {
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "../../controller/inline.php",
              data: "[your-data]",
              success: function(data){
                  $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                  $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
              }
          });
      }, 1000);
  });
```