# Rails, auto-submit form after input blur returns: ActionController::UnknownFormat

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

> The Goal: **Auto submit the form after blur from any input.**

## My approach:

Using `remote: true` in the form, to tell Rails I want to submit via Ajax, then in controller#create, I added a `respond_to` block and finally, I also created the `create.js.erb` file to complete.

And that's working just fine **if someone clicks 'submit'**... but what about auto-submit when `blur`? To achieve that, I followed [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857042/3043906) and added an `autoSubmitForm()` function, but didn't work, showing this error:

## Now, the error:

```
Started POST "/e/0-8d5ac093-3611-4b46-a220-41eb880e6732/elements/10/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-08 15:41:38 -0600
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MZQoS9PsHn50pAXmPUnbk2NjzgLOSps0rn87hYw/lyXD96N0EyzRXTVChazenb1AxL9GnpZ/GH7do3LsEp9zUg==", "answer"=>{"message"=>"MTY"}, "profile_id"=>"0-8d5ac093-3611-4b46-a220-41eb880e6732", "element_id"=>"10"}
  Profile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."profileable_id" = $1 AND "profiles"."profileable_type" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["profileable_id", 2], ["profileable_type", "User"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Element Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "elements".* FROM "elements" WHERE "elements"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 10], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("element_id", "message", "created_at", "updated_at", "profile_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["element_id", 10], ["message", "MTY"], ["created_at", "2018-03-08 21:41:38.121299"], ["updated_at", "2018-03-08 21:41:38.121299"], ["profile_id", 4]]
   (6.0ms)  COMMIT
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 6.8ms)



ActionController::UnknownFormat - ActionController::UnknownFormat:
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:9:in `create'

Started POST "/__better_errors/f572adc255d87208/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-08 15:41:38 -0600


ActionController::UnknownFormat - ActionController::UnknownFormat:
  app/controllers/answers_controller.rb:9:in `create'

Started POST "/__better_errors/f572adc255d87208/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-08 15:41:38 -0600
```

I also tried adding `onchange: 'this.form.submit();'` to input, but it returns the same error.

The post is created ok, but it breaks when implementing `respond_to`.

#### auto_submit_function.js

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  autoSubmitForm()
})

function autoSubmitForm() {
  $('form :input').blur(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
  });
}
```

#### controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user! # I'm using devise

  def create
    @answer = Post.new(posts_params)
    @answer.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  private

  def posts_params
    params.permit(:post).require(:message)
  end
end
```

#### _form.html.haml

```
= form_for [article, post], 
  remote: true, 
  authenticity_token: true, 
  html: { id: "new_post_#{article.id}" } do |form|

  = form.text_field :message
  = form.label :message
  = form.submit
```

#### create.js.erb

```
console.log('I can take it from here, thanks!')
```

Comment: can you please post complete server error log...

Comment: @GaneshNavale, just updated with complete server error log, and thanks for taking the to review it.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a slightly different approach.

Instead of:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  autoSubmitForm()
})

function autoSubmitForm() {
  $('form :input').blur(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit(); // <<<<< Remove this
    $('#submit_' + $(this).attr('id')).trigger('click'); // <<< Add this
  });
}
```

And add a custom id for each `submit` button (I have multiple forms in the same view). Also, I hide with css the submit button.

Basically, instead of `auto submit` I'm `auto clicking` on submit.

Even when this works, It feels like there should be a better solution for this scenario.